Laravel no procesa varias peticiones al mismo tiempo
estoy creando un nuevo proyecto, pero al ejecutar una función(que consume una APIs) que tarda aproximadamente 5 segundos en procesar, y hacer pruebas con varios usuarios, laravel no me esta ejecutando simultáneamente las peticiones, espera a se termine el proceso del primer usuario que dio clic, después procesa al segundo usuario y así sucesivamente. no entiendo que esta pasando porque he trabajado varios proyectos y nunca había pasado esto, estoy haciendo mal alguna configuración?
La misma función, con la misma lógica, en laravel 9.2 y php 8.0.2 no tiene ese comportamiento. el proyecto actual es en laravel 10.10 y php 8.1

Seria bueno saber que es lo que estás procesando cuando los usuarios hacen click en el botón.

si lo comente: 'pero al ejecutar una función(que consume una APIs)'

Yo se por que eso pasa...

@FranciscoNuñezIALover me puedes ayudar?

Si claro, lo primero que ocurre es que no hay codigo para que se ejecute... inicialmente cuando quieres que laravel procese varias peticiones necesitas escribir un codigo en php y javascript que lo haga.

bha y otra cosa te recomiendo hacer el [tour]
